# Selenium server doesn't work with page after it was redirected

Tags: php, ajax, selenium

I have a page which is like a splash screen. It performs some work and when it is complete it sends a request with ajax to main application. Main application should redirect to other page if everything is correct.

When I test it on selenium server, it doesn't work properly. It sends test failed after splash screen page. Like it doesn't see the redirection and can't search new contents for specified text.

**UPD:** Also it gives such error

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Response from Selenium RC server for getLocation().
ERROR Server Exception: sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?.
```

Comment: Could you post some details - particularly, the part of your test that fails ?

Comment: @RabidFX The part where I send ajax query to PHP script and it checks whether data was valid. If it was, it makes redirect to specified location with code 302. Sorry, but I can't place any sort of code from that application here, but feel free to ask me for certain details.

Comment: From the error it seems like your selenium object is no longer available. Can we see your test script?

Answer (score 0):

Try using browser with elevated security privileges, like *chrome for firefox

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone else stumbling across this, I had a similar problem, but for me I had called `setBrowserUrl` with the wrong address - it was the address of my page under test, but it should be the base href of the site.  So the 302 Redirect was actually set relative to the value I had passed to `setBrowserUrl` which landed me at an error page (despite the redirect working perfectly through a normal browser).

To fix the problem I called `setBrowserUrl` with the main site URL (where all relative links are relative to) and then called `url` in each test to set the page under test.  This got things working again.